# Counting vowels in a string

Tags: java

I got 3 strings from the user as input.Then count the vowels in each word and print as follows.If the vowel count = 0 and 1 then print 0.If the vowel count = 2 then print 2.If the vowel count is greater than or equal to 3 then print 3.
I tried this code.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] str = new String[3];
    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) 
        str[i] = in .nextLine();
    for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
        String s1 = str[j];
        String s = s1.toLowerCase();

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i<s.length(); i++) 
        {
            if (s.charAt(i) == 'a' || s.charAt(i) == 'e' || s.charAt(i) == 'i' || s.charAt(i) == 'o' || s.charAt(i) == 'u') {
                count++;
            }
            if (s.charAt(i) == ' ') {
                if (count == 0||count == 1) {
                    System.out.print("0");
                } else if (count == 2) {
                    System.out.print("1");
                } else {
                    System.out.print("3");
                } 
                count = 0;
            }

        }
        if (count == 0||count == 1) {
            System.out.println("0");
        } else if (count == 2) {
            System.out.println("1");
        } else {
            System.out.println("3");
        }
    }
```

But there is one condition only print the vowel count for 3 words only even if the user enter the string with more than 3 words.For eg if the user gives the string "hi hello all, how are you,I am fine and u" it prints "010
011
001" like this only but this code prints as "010
011
00100".Now how can i change the code to print the vowel count only for 3 words and not for more than 3?

Comment: Add a wordcount and break from the inner loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your code **a lot** and it will be easier to achieve what you want. Instead of loop on each char, you can split your string. And then loop on the words. Something like this:

```java
for (int j = 0; j<3; j++) {
    String[] words = str[j].toLowerCase().split(" ");

    // Use Math.min, thanks that it works even if you have only 2 words
    for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(3, words.length()); i++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (char letter : words[i].toCharArray()) {
           // if letter is vowel: count += 1;
        }
        // System.out.println depending on count value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of a break after the third word. One option would be to make an extra variable for tracking it and increment it when the character is space. After 3 words you could break the loop.

Other option would be to split the String into words with `split()` method and the iterate over the first 3 only.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Regex to split words into a sentence, using this method:

```
String[] splits = myPhrase.split(" ");
```

to split words in a sentence, **but** you have to be careful that if the user enters more spaces, the first one is "eliminated" and those just after end up in the split.
For example:

```
String phrase = "1 2  3   z";
String[] splits = phrase.split(" ");
```

generates this array: `[1|2| |3| | |z]`.

So, in my opinion, at that point you could use a filter, go through the array / list again eliminating any space derived from the regex **or** more simply when you scroll through the array / list and find a space you don't consider it.
At this point go to analyze the first 3 elements of the array / list, discarding the others (maybe using a counter).

Finally, again using a Regex, you can also check if the character you are analyzing is a vowel or not using this command:

```
if (s.charAt(i).matches("[AEIOUaeiou]")){ /*it's a vowel*/}
```